# How te keep old app version after releasing new update on iPhone

Tags: iphone, distribution

Is it possible that users who bought an app can keep the old version and also the new one?

Or if for some reason there is a problem with the new version revert to the old one?

I would like to somehow make this possible, since - even though the new update has been tested thoroughly - the app communicates with special devices and if the new update for some reason does not work anymore with some of those older devices I like the user to be able to go back to the previous app update and not be disappointed or angry after the update.

And updating an app on iPhone easily takes a week or longer, so that the developr cannot really quickly respond and just revert the app on iTunes in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get back to the old app is to restore an appropriate iTunes backup ...